# How to Learn advanced concepts in developing Web Servers

Tags: c, sockets, webserver

I recently wrote a small C code which uses sockets to listen on a port. It simply echos back the request made to it by a browser. It creates a thread for daemon process and also for servicing new requests. I am doing it simply to learn more about webservers in general. I wanted to know what to do ahead?

I was planning to read the RFC for http. Many questions already answered on StackOverflow suggest going through open source webserver like apache or lighthttp, but I dont know how to start reading such open source projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.amazon.co.uk/HTTP-Essentials-Protocols-Secure-Scaleable/dp/0471398233/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1307002941&sr=8-1) is a really good book on HTTP. I recommend getting started with that then maybe the relevant RFC's. Also maybe check out the source of [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), a c library for http, https, ftp etc. Hope this helps :)

Also [Tiny HTTPd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyhttpd/) is a small http server someone wrote for a school project, you can learn a lot from the source from that. 
[This](http://coding.debuntu.org/c-linux-socket-programming-tcp-simple-http-client) is simple http client in c.